# Django forms with prefixes not updating on save()

Tags: django, forms

I iterate through a list of Block objects, instantiate a ModelForm for each of them with a mapping dictionary that links a block_type to a ModelForm model, and then append the form to a list which I pass off to a template for display.

```
    for block in blocks:
        block_instance = block_map[block.block_type].objects.get(id=block.id)
        new_form = block_forms[block.block_type]
        new_form_instance = new_form(
            request.user, 
            request.POST or None, 
            instance=block_instance,
            prefix = block.id
        )
        form_zones.append(new_form_instance)
```

Later, while checking request.POST I validate each form

```
    if request.POST.get("save_submit"):
        for zone_form_check in story_zones:
            for block_form_check in zone_form_check:
                if block_form_check.is_valid():
                    print(block_form_check.cleaned_data.get("content"))
                    saved = block_form_check.save()
                    print(saved.content)
                    valid = True
    if valid:
        return redirect("Editorial:content", content_id=content_id)
```

cleaned_data.get("content") produces the updated data, but even after calling save() on the valid form, saved.content produces the object's old content attribute. In other words, a valid form is having save() called upon it, but it is not saving.

One of the forms in question (and currently my only one) is:

```
class Edit_Text_Block_Form(ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea(
        attrs = {
            "class": "full_tinymce"
        }),
        label = "",
    )

    class Meta:
        model = TextBlock
        fields = []

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = user
        super(Edit_Text_Block_Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

The model in question is a TextBlock, which inherits from a Block objets. Both of those are below:

```
class Block(models.Model):
    zone = models.ForeignKey(Zone)
    order = models.IntegerField()
    weight = models.IntegerField()
    block_type = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order']

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Calling custom delete methods of child blocks

        child = block_map[self.block_type].objects.get(id=self.id)
        if getattr(child, "custom_delete", None):
            child.custom_delete()

        # Overriding delete to check if there are any other blocks in the zone.
        # If not, the zone itself is deleted

        zones = Block.objects.filter(zone=self.zone).count()
        if zones <= 1:
             self.zone.delete()

    # Children of Block Object
    class TextBlock(Block):
         content = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

Any ideas for why calling saved = block_form_check.save() isn't updating my model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because you've effectively excluded all the model fields from the form by setting `fields = []` in the form's Meta class. This means that Django no longer relates the manually-defined `content` field on the form with the one in the model.

Instead, set fields to `['content']`, and it should work as expected.

Answer (score -1):

TL;DR form name cannot start with a number as per [html4 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name)

Try prefix = "block_%s" % block.id